# Reiniciando contagem do progressbar c#

Tags: c#

Tenho no meu codigo uma progressBar, que e preenchido em 60 segundos, como faço pra que quando chegar em 60 segundo ele começar a contagem novamente.

```
private void timer_progress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pro_separacao.Increment(1);
}
```

Comment: Você quer uma progress bar infinita?

Comment: Obrigado Linq pela atenção, eu não entendi o que vc quer dizer como infinita, mas hoje no meu código minha progressbar enche com 60 segundos e para, preciso que quando ela encher em 60 segundo ele comece a do 0 novamente e comece a encher de novo e assim sucessivamente de 60 em 60 segundo ate o usuário sair da tela.

Comment: Tipo como se chegasse a 60 segundo desse um refresh no meu windowsform.

Answer (score 0):

Declara uma variável int fora do Timer.

depois no seu timer faça isso, bem simples:

```
 private int segundos;
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     segundos++;
     pro_separacao.Value = segundos;

     if (segundos >= 60)
         segundos = 0;
 }
```